# Normalize CSS filters with GD lib filters

Tags: php, css, image-processing, css-filters, gdlib

I want to make the user drag a rangeslider and adjust brightness and contrast of an image with live preview ( CSS filters ) and then save the adjustments with GD lib.

However i can't seem to get the same result from CSS filters and GD lib BRIGHTNESS and CONTRAST filters.

My css filters are ranging from 50% - 150% with 100% being no effect.

PHP conversion at the moment:

```
    // Convert palette images to true color RGB images
    imagepalettetotruecolor($image);

    if( isset($opt['brightness']) ) {
        $normalize = $opt['brightness'] / 100;
        $brightness = (255 - (255 * $normalize )) * -1;
        imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_BRIGHTNESS, $brightness);
    }

    if( isset($opt['contrast']) ) {
        $contrast = -($opt['contrast'] - 100);
        imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, $contrast);
    }

    imagejpeg($image, $plain_img_path);
```

***CSS filters are the ones with sliders. GD lib without.***

Low contrast:

[image]

[image]

High Brightness:

[image: Brightness GD lib]
[image: Brightness CSS]

Comment: Could you provide an example showing the differences between the GD functions and the CSS filters?

Comment: @Brandito +added images

Comment: Any luck @AndersD? I'm having a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64188292/dynamically-filter-images-in-drupal-7

Comment: @JacobRussell I saved the css values in DB and displayed the images with those css filter values in frontend, so no luck, but i actually thinks this works better for my scenario.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!